# MouseDown event of image in usercontrol not fireing

Tags: c#, wpf, events, routed-events

I made a usercontrol in WPF with an image in it. I declared a `MouseDown` event for this image:

```
<Image x:Name="imgState" Height="300" Width="300" MouseDown="imgState_MouseDown" OpacityMask="#00000000" />
```

I placed this usercontrol on my application form, but the event isn't fireing. I'm pretty new to WPF and I read about `RoutedEvents` but I don't really understand it. I would be happy if someone could help and explain this to me!

**Update**

Changing to PreviewMouseDown didn't fire the event too. I tried setting the background to transparent and even tried with a blank 300x300 image. The grid workaround doesn't fire the event too. Here is how my code behind looks like:

```
private void imgState_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
//Some code here
}
```

**Update 2**

Here is my whole XAML file:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TicTacToe.controls.SingleField"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="imgState" MouseDown="imgState_MouseDown"  Height="300" Width="300" Stretch="None" OpacityMask="#00000000"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I removed the source again because I set one from code behind at runtime and adding a transparent/clear image didn't helped.

Comment: What's the handler `imgState_MouseDown` look like in the code behind for the user control?

Comment: Try setting the background to Transparent.  From the xaml you posted, there is nothing for the mouse event to hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved the problem myself.

The problem was the setting `OpacityMask="#00000000"` that prevented the image from appearing so there were, as [@lll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/493389/lll) said, nothing to hit. I don't know when the setting was set, but I think it happened automatically while expanding the `Representation` tab.

**Thanks for helping me!**

Answer (score 1):

You probably want **PreviewMouseUp** instead of **MouseDown** event

```
<Image x:Name="imgState" Height="300" Width="300" 
 PreviewMouseUp="ImgState_OnPreviewMouseUp" 
 PreviewMouseDown="ImgState_OnPreviewMouseDown"/>
```

Either of the two, you can capture the event from there.

Comment: Please see my update :) Could you explain me the drifference between **PreviewMouseDown** and **MouseDown**? MSDN says the **PreviewMouseDown** is fireing when a mouse button is pressed and is above a control, **MouseDown** fires when a mouse button is pressed (Shouldn't this event only fire when the mouse is above the control too?)

Comment: Show me your entire XAML. Where is this image sitting? What is its parent?

Comment: Added that, parent is a `Grid`

Comment: Does the image has a source? If it doesn't have anything to show then yes no events will be fired.

Comment: As I said, I tried with transparent background color, transparent 300x300 image and a white 300x300 image. Should I upload the project, so you can have a look in it? It's a VS2013 project

Comment: Thank you, but I solved the problem myself, see my answer if you want to know the solution

Answer (score 0):

If the answer above does not help:

Not a very nice solution but does work so many times:

Wrap your image with a grid on which you will have your event...

```
<Grid MouseDown="imgState_MouseDown">
<Image/>
</Grid>
```